# Why is redirect_uri required on Access Token request?

Tags: oauth-2.0, rfc6749

I'm developing an oauth2 provider based on [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and I'm wondering, why is redirect_uri required on the [Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)? The /token endpoint is not redirecting and the state is assumed to be already validated (i.e. against CSRF) so a copy of the redirectURI doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

In auth code flow, it's used to validate the redirect_uri in the first auth request.
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-validation/

> **Granting Access Tokens**
>
> The token endpoint will get a request to exchange an authorization
>   code for an access token. This request will contain a redirect URL as
>   well as the authorization code. As an added measure of security, the
>   server should verify that the redirect URL in this request matches
>   exactly the redirect URL that was included in the initial
>   authorization request for this authorization code. If the redirect URL
>   does not match, the server rejects the request with an error.

Comment: This is really counter-intuitive, but can be very important. I was refactoring an OAuth2 consumer in a project and stuff broke because of this, costing hours of debugging. At the same time, I highly doubt the security value of the extra check. Say the OAuth code (which is not bruteforceable) is leaked because someone copy-pasted the entire URL, then isn't the redirect_uri also leaked??

Answer (score 2):

The same question is debated here : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44214/what-is-the-purpose-of-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-checking.

[The best response imho is vinod one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/98049/108905) ie. to reduce the surface attack when using flexible redirect_uri (using wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

I went and emailed the original author of RFC 6749, Dick Hardt, to ask him about this. He responded as follows:

> An attacker may have modified the redirect_uri being sent to the AS so that it can get the response and modify it.
>
> As it turns out, there does not seem to be attacks that would be thwarted by passing the redirect_uri to the token endpoint, and we are considering dropping it in OAuth 2.1.

I don't think this additional requirement is justified.

If the attacker already misdirected the client to an adversarial redirect_uri, they will know this redirect_uri when they do a /token request so it won't prevent them from obtaining an access token

If they somehow obtain the authorization code through a leaky callback, they'll get this through a referer header and parse it from the param string, but this means they'll have the entire URL (i.e. the redirect_uri)

I can't think of a scenario where the attacker obtains the authorization code, but not the redirect_uri

Answer (score -1):

Redirect URI is needed in case of 
1. Authorization code flow where Server redirects with code to the redirect URI, for example sample response to Authorization request is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.example.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
           &state=xyz
```

Same is true for Error response for Authz code flow:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.example.com/cb?error=access_denied&state=xyz
```

Incase of implicit grant as well, Server returns the access token in hash "#" fragement to the redirect URI provided in the request