# Understanding the flow of OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

I'm new to OAuth2 and I'm trying to understand the whole flow of things. For context, I'm thinking of making a web dashboard where users log in via Discord's OAuth2 API.

This is how I think the flow works based on my understanding so far:

1. User goes to my site and clicks a login link
2. My site redirects them to Discord with my *client ID* and a *redirect URL #1* in the query string
3. Discord redirects them back to my site at *redirect URL #1* with an *authorisation code* in the query string
4. My site takes this *authorisation code* and along with my *client ID*, *client secret* and **redirect URL #2**, uses all these to fetch an **access token** and *refresh token* from Discord
5. If I do get an *access token*, that means the user is now "logged in" (*authorisation code* worked)
6. My site finally redirects the user to a **page** and is now free to send requests to Discord's API with the *access token*, while saving the *access token* and *refresh token*. Just for example, say the *page* states their Discord username

I'm learning from [this guide](https://medium.com/@orels1/using-discord-oauth2-a-simple-guide-and-an-example-nodejs-app-71a9e032770), and what confuses me is [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/orels1/3495352b88bd60299181e3252db15f76#file-discord-js) from the guide. At line 5, it provides the **redirect URL #2** mentioned above, in the query string. I'm not sure what it's for.

Also, I'm not very sure how to continue once I have the **access token**. If multiple users log in, I'd have multiple *access tokens* on hand. Say a user wants to access the **page** again, how do I uniquely identify them and know which *access token* to use to send requests to Discord's API? (for this example, the request would give me their username which I'd display on the *page*)

Yeah, I probably got a lot of concepts wrong. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I've done more research into this, and found a [much better guide here](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#oauth2-flows).

For my question about the second redirect URL, the examples in the [official documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) specify a `redirect_uri` when doing both an access token and a refresh token exchange. However, this new guide makes do without for their access token exchange. Perhaps they missed it out? As this [other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659188/why-is-redirect-uri-required-on-access-token-request) says:

> As an added measure of security, the server should verify that the redirect URL in this request matches exactly the redirect URL that was included in the initial authorization request for this authorization code. If the redirect URL does not match, the server rejects the request with an error.

I suppose this means that after the first access token exchange, any refresh token exchanges or straight up API requests with access tokens need to match the original `redirect_uri` of said first access token exchange. So I should use one and only one `redirect_uri`, and the refresh token exchanges/API requests do not actually use the `redirect_uri`, rather it's used for further security.

As for the whole login procedure, it seems I have to link the access & refresh tokens I obtain to a user session, and for that I'll look into using this passport strategy, [passport-discord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-discord). Then, once the session expires, I'll discard the two tokens, and they'll have to click login again, but I can make use of this `prompt` option:

> prompt controls how the authorization flow handles existing authorizations. If a user has previously authorized your application with the requested scopes and prompt is set to consent, it will request them to reapprove their authorisation. If set to none, it will skip the authorization screen and redirect them back to your redirect URI without requesting their authorization.

From there I think I'd just store the new access and refresh tokens associated with that user.

I'd really appreciate if any mistakes in my thought process could be pointed out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your summary seems good to me Mr Cloud - worth clarifying whether you are developing an SPA or (old) web app with a server side. Most commonly the first is cookieless, whereas the second stores a refresh token in a cookie. A key thing is to understand what the OAuth message workflow looks like. For SPAs and APIs this write up of mine may help you clarify what you want: https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/
Happy to answer any follow on questions ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implicit grant to use with SPA
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#implicit-grant